# Al asignar un valor a un select este se carga pero se desaparece al finalizar la instruccion con jquery

Tags: jquery, select, bootstrap-4

Muy buenas tardes estimada comunidad,

Un gusto saludarlos y esperando que estén muy bien. Quiero preguntarles por un problema que me aparece y es que tengo varios select que cargo desde la base de datos, al dar clic en editar, debo cargar desde la base de datos la informacion guardada y asignarla a cada elemento, primero cargo los select y luego le asigno la variable que traigo de la base de datos y de allí los inputs, el problema que tengo es: que el valor traido de la bd se asigna al select, lo se porque lo valido con un paso a paso con el debug pero al entrar en la librería jquery restablece el valor del select solo de estos y no de los inputs, esto lo hace cuando lee algunas lineas propias de código de jquery. mi objetivo como lo saben es dejar asignado el valor traido de la BD. les dejo mi código para que por favor me guíen y si ven que es necesario que cambie el código para evitar este problema. De antemano muchas gracias

```
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Proyecto</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    .mostrar{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns:  repeat(3, 100px) 40px;
      grid-gap: 1em;
      margin: 20px; 
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mostrarModal();">Crear</button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary .link-editar">Editar</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      .  <div class="mostrar">

        <select class="form-control tnq" id="cmbTanque1"></select>
        <input type="number" class="form-control tnq" id="txtCantidad1" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input type="number" class="form-control tnq" id="txtTotal1" placeholder="Total" readonly>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btnEliminar1" type="button">X</button>
    
        <select class="form-control tnq" id="cmbTanque2"></select>
        <input type="number" class="form-control tnq" id="txtCantidad2" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input type="number" class="form-control tnq" id="txtTotal2" placeholder="Total" readonly>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btnEliminar2" type="button">X</button>
    
        <select class="form-control tnq" id="cmbTanque3"></select>
        <input type="number" class="form-control tnq" id="txtCantidad3" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input type="number" class="form-control tnq" id="txtTotal3" placeholder="Total" readonly>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btnEliminar3" type="button">X</button>
    
        <select class="form-control tnq" id="cmbTanque4"></select>
        <input type="number" class="form-control tnq" id="txtCantidad4" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input type="number" class="form-control tnq" id="txtTotal4" placeholder="Total" readonly>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btnEliminar4" type="button">X</button>
    
        <select class="form-control tnq" id="cmbTanque5"></select>
        <input type="number" class="form-control tnq" id="txtCantidad5" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input type="number" class="form-control tnq" id="txtTotal5" placeholder="Total" readonly>
        <button class="btn btn-warning eliminarTanque" id="btnEliminar5" type="button">X</button>
        
        <label for="" class="labelTotalTanques">Total</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control sumaTanques tnq" id="sumaTanques" readonly>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- jquery -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!-- <script src="js/utils/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script> -->

<script>
  function mostrarModal(){
    $('#exampleModalLongTitle').show();
    cargarTanques();
  }
</script>

  <script>
    
function cargarTanques() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        'url' : 'php/listarBatch.php',
        'data':{"operacion" : "9"},
        success: function(r){
            var info = JSON.parse(r);
            
            for (i=1; i<6; i++){
                $('#cmbTanque'+i).empty();
                let $select = $('#cmbTanque'+ i);
                $select.append('<option disabled selected>' + "Tanque" + '</option>');    
                $.each(info, function(i, value) {
                    $select.append('<option value ="'+  value.capacidad + '">' + value.capacidad + '</option>');
                 })

            }
        }
    })
}
  </script>

<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.link-editar', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    editar = true;

    var texto = $(this).parent().parent().children()[1];
    var id = $(texto).text();
    
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url : 'php/listarBatch.php',
        data: {operacion : "6", id : id},  
        
         success: function(response){
            
            var info = JSON.parse(response);
            let sum = 0;

            $('#idbatch').val(info[0].id_batch);
            $('#referencia').val(info[0].referencia);
            $('#nombrereferencia').val(info[0].nombre_referencia);

            unidades = info[0].unidad_lote;
            lote = info[0].tamano_lote;
            
            $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show');            
            $('.labelTotalTanques').show();
            $('.sumaTanques').show();
            
            cargarTanques();

            for(k=1; k<info.length; k++){
                const cantidad = info[k].cantidad
                const tanque= info[k].tanque
                const total = cantidad * tanque
                
                $('#cmbTanque' + k).show().val(tanque);
                $('#txtCantidad' + k).show().val(cantidad);
                $('#txtTotal' + k).show().val(total);
                $('#btnEliminar' + k).show();
                
                sum = sum + total;
                $('.sumatanques').val(sum);
            }
            
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        } 
    })
})


</script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Hola Sergio. Aquí estás limpiando los `select`: **`$('#cmbTanque'+i).empty();`** Si lo que quieres es que los nuevos valores sean agregados a los mismos prueba a comentar o borrar esa línea.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, muchas gracias por tu amable respuesta, esta linea la coloco porque de no ser asi, cada vez que cargo el select se repiten los datos, sin embargo probe lo que me dices y pasa lo mismo, a los select les asigno la informacion correctamente pero veo que cuando ingresa a jquery los regresa a su valor como si apenas los recargara y borra la asignacion

Comment: No entiendo bien si lo que ocurre es que la página se está recargando. Prueba a poner al final de `mostrarModal()` y/o al final de `cargarTanques()` el siguiente código: `return false;`

Comment: Muchas gracias A. Cedano, me sirvió tu guía, tienes razón se estaba recargando. lo que hice fue mover la función de cargarTanques() para cuando se inicializa el proceso y funciono perfecto :)